# Separate a row of comma delimited strings into separate rows

Tags: python, ruby, shell, csv, ubuntu

Example Input csv file:

```
Email,Division,Department
```

Expected output:

```
Email,Division,Department
```

Comment: Interesting problem. Could you be more specific as to where you're stuck? Do you know the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) already?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
require 'csv'

csv = File.read('input_csv')

rows = csv.split("\n")
rows = rows.map do |i| 
    fields = i.parse_csv
    fields.map{ |j| j.include?(",") ? j.split(",")[1] : j}
end
puts rows.to_s
# [["Email", "Division", "Department"], ["john@example.com", "ux", "ui"], ["tom@example.com", "prod", "prod"], ["alex@example.com", "sales", "sales"]]
```

Assuming you want to output rows to an output CSV:

```
CSV.open("output.csv", "w") do |csv|
    rows.each { |row| csv << row }
end
```